# RSpec it block with variable name

Tags: unit-testing, rspec

I have a function `get_type` that returns a string given an int:

```
def get_type(integer)
    types = [...]
    return types[integer]
end
```

When testing with RSpec, I tried doing the following:

```
describe 'function' do
    context 'on valid input'
        let(:input){ 2 }
        let(:type){ 'large' }
        let(:result){ get_type input }
        it{ expect(result).to eq(type) }
    end
end
```

However, this gives the message:

```
function on valid input should eq "large"
```

without any mention to the input, thus sounding like the function should always return `"large"`.

How should this message be changed to say something like:

```
function on valid input should eq type
```

or another meaningful message? I could name the `it` block:

```
it 'should have the correct type' do
    expect(result).to eq(type)
end
```

but is there a nicer way to do this without essentially typing out the test twice?

Answer (score 0):

I think the unhelpful message should be considered a smell - you're headed down a road where every test is just `expect(result).to eq(expected)` with a wall of `let`. To my mind this is overuse of `let` - I don't think you gain anything over

```
describe 'function' do
   context 'on valid input' do
     it{ expect(get_type(2)).to eq('large') }
   end
end
```

Which would produce a more helpful failure message. I would keep `let` for when the expressions are more complex or when I can give them a better name (eg a hash of attributes called `valid_attributes`)